# How do I check if a column from a SQL database cursor is empty?

Tags: java, android, cursor

I have database where they can enter in an image as one of the fields. The image is saved onto the phone and the URI is saved into the database.

I'm having trouble when the user decides to not put in an image for an item.

I'm trying to write an if/else statement, where the "if" condition checks if the cursor's image column is null. I just can't figure out what to type into the if condition.

Here is the bit of code I'm working with. Basically I want to make it so that if the cursor's COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE is null, just make a toast. If it's not null, then set the image.

```
//This section turns the database's image URI stored in this cursor into a bitmap, and then sets the ImageView.
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        if (............){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No image was taken for this item. (TOAST IS JUST TESTING PURPOSES)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE))));
            mFullImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is an example of one of the things I tried with no success:

```
if (Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE))).equals(null)){ 

//This returns error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jeremy.sqlwine/com.example.jeremy.sqlwine.DetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the column value in a separate method. Then check the return value before using it.

Try something like this:

```
private String checkDatabaseValue(Cursor cursor){
    String result = null;
    try{
        //This can throw an error if the column is not found
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE);
        result = cursor.getString(index).trim();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // determine what threw the error and handle appropriately
        Log.e(TAG, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then use it here:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        // I'm assuming you have the cursor from somewhere!!
        String imageFile = checkDatabaseValue(cursor);
        if (imageFile == null){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No image was taken for this item. (TOAST IS JUST TESTING PURPOSES)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if(!imageFile.isEmpty()){
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(imageFile));
            mFullImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Empty String. (TOAST IS JUST TESTING PURPOSES)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This worked wonderfully. Thanks a lot. I'm not too good at thinking up methods like that yet. I hope I can improve on that. Thanks for providing a method like that. Now I have a good example on how I should be thinking for projects like this.

Comment: While you are still learning (and aren't we all, really) try not to use compound statements like this ::  `Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE)))`  :: It is hard to see what went wrong, where it went wrong and why. Break everything down so that you can check each value.

Answer (score 0):

use this instead:

```
if(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE) == null)
```

update :

```
cursor.isNull(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(WineContract.WineEntry.COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE))
```

Comment: The problem with this though is that it just gets the integer of that index, right? Unless I'm mistaken. Either way, when I try it that way it has a red underline that says: Operator "==" cannot be applied to 'int', 'null'